# How to change the format of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `df` in the following format:

```
df =
MONTH   WEEKDAY   EVAL
1       0         1
1       0         0
1       0         0
1       1         1
1       1         0
2       0         0
2       0         0
2       1         1
```

I am grouping the data as follows:

```
result = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','EVAL']).size().reset_index()
result
```

The way in which it outputs the result is different from what I want to get:

```
MONTH  WEEKDAY  EVAL  0
1      0        0     400
1      0        1     20
1      1        0     300 
1      1        1     20
2      0        0     200
2      0        1     35
2      1        0     450
2      1        1     26
```

I want to change the format of `result` to this one:

```
WEEKDAY   EVAL_0   EVAL_1
0         400      20
0         200      35
1         300      20
1         450      26
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then some data cleaning is necessary:

```
df = df.set_index(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','EVAL'])['0'].unstack()

#if get ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
#if duplicates and necessary aggregate data with mean, sum...
#df = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','EVAL'])['0'].mean().unstack()
#df = df.pivot_table(index=['MONTH','WEEKDAY'], columns='EVAL', values='0', aggfunc='mean')

print (df)
EVAL             0   1
MONTH WEEKDAY         
1     0        400  20
      1        300  20
2     0        200  35
      1        450  26

df = df.sort_index(level=[1,0])
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .add_prefix('EVAL_')
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   WEEKDAY  EVAL_0  EVAL_1
0        0     400      20
1        0     200      35
2        1     300      20
3        1     450      26
```

Sample with duplicates:

```
print (df)
   MONTH  WEEKDAY  EVAL    0
0      1        0     0  400
1      1        0     1   20
2      1        1     0  300
3      1        1     1   20
4      2        0     0  200
5      2        0     1   35
6      2        1     0  450
7      2        1     1   26
8      2        1     1  100 <-duplicate

df = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','EVAL'])['0'].mean().unstack()

df = df.sort_index(level=[1,0])
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
       .add_prefix('EVAL_')
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   WEEKDAY  EVAL_0  EVAL_1
0        0     400      20
1        0     200      35
2        1     300      20
3        1     450      63 <- value is mean of (100 + 26)/2
```

Comment: It worked for me when I changed `['0'].unstack()` to `[0].unstack()`. Thanks.

Comment: I forget, sorry. You can change `0` to same value by `result = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','EVAL']).size().reset_index(name='COL')`. Thank you.